# Chart.js Box Annotations Fill Entire Chart

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to plot a simple chart, but want to colour the upper and lower parts of the chart red to indicate a value out of range, and the center part of the chart green to indicate an acceptable value.

Using chartjs-plugin-annotation.js and three Box Annotations, I am almost there.  Unfortunately the three boxes don't seem to want to honour the 'yMax' and 'yMin' coordinates I specify.  The boxes expand out to the edges in the Y direction.  This is what I want them to do in the X direction.  But in the Y direction I'm trying to specify the demarcation between the central, green "ok" area and the upper and lower "danger" zones.

If someone can point me in the direction of a solution, I'd very much appreciate it!  Here is my code attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Chart</title>
    <script src='./moment.js'></script>
    <script src='./Chart.js'></script>
    <script src='./chartjs-plugin-annotation.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id='TestChart' width='1200' height='300'>
    <script>
      var user_notes = [ '','','','','Note One','','','','',
                        'Note Two','','','','','','','','','','' ];
      new Chart (
        document.getElementById( 'TestChart' ), {
          'type' : 'line',
          'data' : {
          'datasets' : [{
            'label' : 'Test Chart',
            'fill' : false,
            'borderColor' : '#000000',
            'colour' : '#c0ffa0',           
            'lineTension' : 0.4, 
            'pointHitRadius' : 10,
            'pointRotation' : 45,
            'pointRadius' : [ 5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 ],
    //          'pointRadius' : (item, data) => {   // function better but 
    //            console.log( 'TEST pointRadius' );// can't get it to work
    //            return 7;
    //          },
            'pointStyle' : [ 'circle','circle','circle','circle','rect',
                              'circle','circle','circle','circle','rect',
                              'circle','circle','circle','circle','circle',
                              'circle','circle','circle','circle','circle' ],         
    //          'pointStyle' : (item, data) => {    // function better but
    //            console.log( 'TEST pointStyle' ); // can't get it to work
    //            return 'triangle';
    //          },
            'pointBackgroundColor' : [ '#ffa0c0', '#ffa0c0', '#ffa0c0',
                                        '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0',
                                        '#c0ffa0', '#ffa0c0', '#c0ffa0',
                                        '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0',
                                        '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0',
                                        '#c0ffa0', '#ffa0c0', '#c0ffa0',
                                        '#c0ffa0', '#c0ffa0' ],                 
    // a function call would be better 
    // but can't get either of the following to work
    //          // function type one
    //          'pointBackgroundColor' : (item, data) => {
    //            console.log( 'pointBackgroundColor TEST' );
    //            return '#c0ffa0';
    //          },

    //          // function type two
    //          'pointBackgroundColor' : function( context ) {
    //            var v = context.dataset.data[c_index];
    //            console.log( 'pointBackgroundColor TEST: v = ' + v );
    //            return
    //                (v <= 3.9) || (v >= 6)
    //                    ? '#ffa0c0'   // draw extreme values in red
    //                    : '#c0ffa0';  // else, values in green
    //          },

            'data' : [
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-03 07:19' ), y: 3.9 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-04 07:31' ), y: 3.8 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-05 08:15' ), y: 3.6 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-06 08:20' ), y: 4.2 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-07 08:08' ), y: 4.2 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-08 08:00' ), y: 4.2 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-09 08:18' ), y: 4.4 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-10 07:59' ), y: 3.5 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-11 08:02' ), y: 4.8 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-12 08:23' ), y: 4.4 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-13 07:54' ), y: 4.0 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-14 08:00' ), y: 4.3 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-15 08:11' ), y: 4.2 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-16 08:11' ), y: 4.9 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-17 08:10' ), y: 4.9 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-18 08:15' ), y: 5.8 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-19 07:10' ), y: 6.1 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-20 08:03' ), y: 5.1 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-21 07:51' ), y: 4.7 },
                { x: new Date( '2019-11-22 07:56' ), y: 4.3 }
            ]
          }]
        },

        options: {
          'point' : {
            'borderColor' : '#000000',
          },

          'tooltips' : {
            'mode' : 'index',
            'bodyFontSize' : 24,
            'footerFontSize' : 18,
            'footerFontColor' : '#ffeb6d',
            'axix' : 'y',
            'callbacks' : {
              'title' : (item, data) => {
                var when = item[0].xLabel.split( ' ' );
                var newT = when[0] + ' ' + when[1] + ' ' + when[3];
                return newT.substring(0, newT.length - 3);
              },
              'label' : (item, data) => {
                return item.yLabel.toFixed( 1 ) + ' Units';
              },
              'footer' : (item, data) => {
                return user_notes[ item[0].index ];
              },
            },
          },        // end tooltips

          'legend' : { 
            'onClick' : 'null',
            // 'display' : 'false',
            'position' : 'top',
          },

          'scales' : {
            'xAxes' : [ {
              'type' : 'time',
              'ticks' : { 
                'time' : { 'displayFormats' : { 'day' : 'D MMM' } },
              } 
            } ],
            'yAxes' : [ {
              'display' : 'true',
              'position' : 'right',
              'ticks' : {
                'suggestedMax' : 9.0,
                'suggestedMin' : 3.0,
              }
            } ],
          },        // end scales

          'annotation' : {
            'drawTime' : 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
            'annotations' : [{
              'type' : 'box',
              'id' : 'top-red',
              'xScaleID' : 'xAxes',
              'yScaleID' : 'yAxes',
              'yMin' : '5.9',        //ignored
              'borderWidth' : 0,
              'borderColor' : 'rgba(255,200,200,0.3)',
              'backgroundColor' : 'rgba(255,200,200,0.3)',
            },{
              'type' : 'box',
              'id' : 'middle-green',
              'xScaleID' : 'xAxes',
              'yScaleID' : 'yAxes',
              'yMax' : '5.9',       // ignored
              'yMin' : '4.0',       // ignored
              'borderWidth' : 0,
              'borderColor' : 'rgba(200,255,200,0.3)',
              'backgroundColor' : 'rgba(200,255,200,0.3)',
            },{
              'type' : 'box',
              'id' : 'bottom-red',
              'xScaleID' : 'xAxes',
              'yScaleID' : 'yAxes',
              'yMax' : '4.0',        // ignored
              'borderWidth' : 0,
              'borderColor' : 'rgba(255,200,200,0.3)',
              'backgroundColor' : 'rgba(255,200,200,0.3)',
            }]
          }         // end annotation
        }       // end options
      }
    );
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior comes from the fact that you did not provide the correct y-axis id and x-axis id in the boxes definition.

I see that you did not put any id for x-axis and y-axis in your chart's xAxes and yAxes definition, so their default ids are 'x-axis-0' and 'y-axis-0'.

For each of your boxes definition, try changing

```
'xScaleID' : 'xAxes',
'yScaleID' : 'yAxes'
```

into

```
'xScaleID' : 'x-axis-0',
'yScaleID' : 'y-axis-0'
```